# alphabetical order combobox (ajax, codeigniter) only works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have my code in codeigniter. The array works fine outside the combobox, but the json object is reorder by the id in chrome and the others browser. I proved everything, and found a solution, but the array now is object object.

The code is this:

The view:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://www.url.com/admin/modificar_contacto/get_clientes/", 
            success: function(nombres) 
            {


               console.log(nombres);
                var temp = [];

               $.each(nombres,function(id,nombre)
                {
                  temp.push({v:id,k:nombre});
                  console.log(temp);
                 });


                 temp.sort(function(a,b){
                     if(a.k > b.k){ return 1}
                     if(a.k < b.k){ return -1}
                        return 0;
                        console.log(temp);
                     });


                  $.each(temp,function(key, obj) {
                       $('#nombres').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+obj+'</option>');
                       });
            }
```

The controller:

```
    function get_clientes(){

  header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
 echo(json_encode($this->contenido_admin_model->get_clientes()));

  }
```

The model:

```
     function get_clientes() {
            $this -> db -> select('cliente_id,cliente_nombre');
            $this->db->order_by("cliente_nombre", "asc");
             $this->db->where('cliente_estado',0);
            $query = $this -> db -> get('ad_cliente');

            $clientes = array();

            if ($query -> result()) {
                    foreach ($query->result_array() as $cliente) {
                            $clientes[$cliente['cliente_id']]=$cliente['cliente_nombre'];   
                    }
                    return $clientes;
            } else {
                    return FALSE;
            }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help. I don´t know what else to do. I´m stuck in this for days...

Comment: So when you print out your data without JavaScript applied, you get right result ? (correctly ordered array?) Do you have to use javascript to create combobox? Because Codeigniter itself can do it for you easily.

Comment: Yes, outside I get the right result...I need to use ajax because I have three results  (for example countries-states-cities) in the same page. The solution I tried was to get the json, create an array, order this result array, and pass the array again. But I get Object Object, and I´m lost now...

Comment: Show us your `object object`. ;)

Comment: I get [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]  instead of id name, id name, id name... :(